# Disecting a Function for speed

Tags: performance, sql-server-2005, function

I wanted to know if there was a way to measure the performance of a function.  In parts.

I know that you are able to measure the total time it takes to complete the function but is there a way to measure the individual queires within a function?

Just wanted to know because I can not find the bottleneck for my function's performance.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan for the queries in the function?

Comment: Yes. Maybe I just dont know how to use them but include actual execution plan is useless for me since it just shows 100% for the function itself.  Estimated Execution plan works better but it just shows a huge image that takes forever to navigate and only shows me percentages.  Does the percentage directly relate to the time it spends on that particular function?

Comment: @user1512593 - Please edit the question to show the function's code to get more specific answers.

Comment: The functions code is about 400 lines long.  I dont think the functions code needs to be provided for a specific answer for this question.

Comment: Pull the contents of the function out and drop it in a query window in SSMS.  When you run it you should get the execution plan in detail.  You'll have to fudge any parameters, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time when you see a major difference between the estimated and the actual execution plans, it is because your statistics have not been (ever) updated.  The SQL Server therefore has no idea which tables have little data, which ones are huge, and so on, and is more likely to generate bogus plans (both estimated and actual), or to miscalculate estimated plan costs.  The actual plan is based on real, accurate costs of the plan, but when the plan is very far from an optimal one, this accuracy is of very little value for determining bottlenecks.

To correct this, issue the `UPDATE STATISTICS` statement or execute the `sp_updatestats` procedure.

Seeing 100% actuals for your function might well be an effect of empty or almost empty database, regardless of whether you have uptodate statistics or not.

When optimizing for performance, make sure that your database is populated quasi-realistically with lots of data (put twice as much records to each table than what you expect for production; but do maintain the expected rough proportions).  There is not much point in looking for a performance bottleneck using an empty or an entirely, disproportionately overblown database; query plans will be different and even if the plan will happen to be the same one, the bottleneck may be elsewhere than in production.

Comment: Okay. I love you. Thank you. Did not find an exact answer but your sp_updatestats did help improve performance by ALOT! Just another question, Do I need to run that for each function or does running it once effect everything?

Comment: @user1512593 - Run it regularly (nightly).  Run it once every time when you drastically change the size/content of a database - initial configuration, return to service, and such.  Don't run it during peaks of normal operation.